# Help to reproduce a tcolorbox with a decoration

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I'm trying to reproduce this box but with the rhombus at the right of the oval box.

[image]

I don't know how to create the rhombus and how to place it that way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, patterns}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor,etoolbox}



\definecolor{boxcolor}{RGB}{50,232,250}

\newtcbox{\exobox}{on line,
arc=7pt,colback=white!10!white,colframe=boxcolor,
before upper={\rule[-3pt]{0pt}{10pt}},boxrule=2pt,
boxsep=0pt,left=12pt,right=12pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt}


\begin{document}
\exobox{ See exercise 3}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the shape `diamond` to draw the rhombus and `overlay` to add it to your `tcolorbox`.

Thanks to Ignasi for pointing out the rhombus should be on the right.

I've created some alternatives, choose which one you like.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes.geometric}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\definecolor{boxcolor}{RGB}{50,232,250}

\newtcbox{\exoboxright}{
    on line,
    arc=7pt,
    colback=white!10!white,
    colframe=boxcolor,
    before upper={\rule[-3pt]{0pt}{10pt}},
    boxrule=2pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    left=12pt,
    right=12pt,
    top=2pt,
    bottom=2pt,
    enhanced,    
    left skip=10pt,
    overlay={%
     \node[draw, boxcolor, diamond, minimum height=18pt, minimum width=18pt, line width=2pt, fill=white, rounded corners] (mynode) at ([xshift=-2pt]frame.west) {};
     \path[rounded corners, fill=boxcolor] (mynode.north) -- (mynode.west) -- (mynode.south) -- cycle;
     \node[circle, fill=white, inner sep=1.4pt] at ([xshift=6pt]mynode.west) {};
    }
}

\newtcbox{\exoboxleft}{
    on line,
    arc=7pt,
    colback=white!10!white,
    colframe=boxcolor,
    before upper={\rule[-3pt]{0pt}{10pt}},
    boxrule=2pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    left=12pt,
    right=12pt,
    top=2pt,
    bottom=2pt,
    enhanced,    
    right skip=10pt,
    overlay={%
     \node[draw, boxcolor, diamond, minimum height=18pt, minimum width=18pt, line width=2pt, fill=white, rounded corners] (mynode) at ([xshift=2pt]frame.east) {};
     \path[rounded corners, fill=boxcolor] (mynode.north) -- (mynode.west) -- (mynode.south) -- cycle;
     \node[circle, fill=white, inner sep=1.4pt] at ([xshift=6pt]mynode.west) {};
    }
}

\newtcbox{\exobox}{
    on line,
    arc=7pt,
    colback=white!10!white,
    colframe=boxcolor,
    before upper={\rule[-3pt]{0pt}{10pt}},
    boxrule=2pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    left=12pt,
    right=12pt,
    top=2pt,
    bottom=2pt,
    enhanced,    
    right skip=10pt,
    overlay={%
     \node[draw, boxcolor, diamond, minimum height=18pt, minimum width=18pt, line width=2pt, fill=white, rounded corners] (mynode) at ([xshift=2pt]frame.east) {};
     \path[rounded corners, fill=boxcolor] (mynode.north) -- (mynode.east) -- (mynode.south) -- cycle;
     \node[circle, fill=white, inner sep=1.4pt] at ([xshift=-6pt]mynode.east) {};
    }
}


\begin{document}
Box with rhombus on the right and decoration mirrored \exobox{See exercise 3}

Box with rhombus on the right \exoboxleft{See exercise 3}

Box with rhombus on the left \exoboxright{See exercise 3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice (+1) but OP says "rombus at the right of oval box"

Comment: @Ignasi Corrected, thanks!

Comment: Thanks to all, that's helpful.

Comment: @Clifford You're welcome and thank you for accepting my answer!